# How to get ZINC 500k dataset?

Tags: datasets, graph-neural-networks

I have been using the ZINC graph regression dataset available through pytorch geometric datasets for a while now in two of its modes (12k examples and 250k examples). However, in the [PapersWithCode comparison](https://paperswithcode.com/dataset/zinc) there is always reference to a dataset with 500k examples that I am unable to find. does anyone know where a download link or something like that might be?

Comment: It might be an error by paperswithcode. I've checked some publications that are listed there and 1) [The paper that published the ZINC dataset](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.00982) says that the full ZINC data consists of 250k samples and their smaller version contains only 12k (s. p.17). 2) The top listed papers all use either the 120k or the 12k-version and the scores they achieve for i.e. 250k are listed in the 500k leaderboard (cf. [this paper p.9](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.12575v3.pdf)). I'm pretty sure this is an error and the dataset should actually be listed as 250k.